# How can I improve the Odinblade and Odinbolt?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

Currently, my Odin* weapons only add 139 physical/magical damage to Serah and Noel. Can I feed them with fragments to improve them?

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you find a fragment, damage gets added until a total of 220 attack or magic damage.

you reach this total when you have found all 160 fragments

Answer (score 1):

Damage is calculated as: number of collected fragments divided by 1.6 then plus 40. A damage bonus of 80 is added once you collect all 160 fragments. This all adds to a maximum of 220.

You must have a few more fragments to collect in order to max the Odin weapons out.